# Low quality Apple Music app audio when doing conference calls

Tags: macos, sound-volume, video-conference

I noticed a mono-like sound switch of current Music app song when starting a video call with Skype or Zoom. Can anyone here help me please?

Comment: I used to deal with that all the time, but I can't reproduce on the latest version of Zoom...are you using 5.0.2?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a Bluetooth headset? If so, try the following:

Go to `System Preferences → Sound → Input` and select a device other than your bluetooth device, for example "MacBook Air Microphone."

Note that if you disconnect your bluetooth device, you might have to do this step over again. Inconvenient, I know.

This is because bluetooth does not have enough bandwidth for 3 audio channels at the same time, so it is either: (1) two speaker channels (stereo) or (2) one speaker channel (mono) and one microphone channel.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow in my next online workout

Comment: Let me know if this was of any help :)